# Where can I get data set for metaphony in Italian dialects?

Tags: phonology, resource-request, italian

The problem is that most sources refer to phonological data collected a long time ago. Where can I get some fresh stuff to analyze?

Comment: Ask your favorite Italian sociolinguist?

Comment: If you want to receive a useful answer you need to add more information ;) 1) What is metaphony? 2) What kind of data do you want (recordings? spontaneous? read speech?)